# Support of ASAN flags in arm-none-eabi toolchain

Tags: c, gcc, toolchain, address-sanitizer

I'm working on porting kernel address sanitizer (KASan) from linux to another os (let's call it OS). This OS compiled with `arm-none-eabi` toolchain and I pass following asan related flags to compiler:

`-fsanitize=kernel-address --param asan-globals=1 --param asan-stack=1 --param asan-instrumentation-with-call-threshold=0`

Also I implement different `__asan_*` functions including `__asan_register_globals` and `__asan_unregister_globals`.

My problem is that compiler inserts only `__asan_load*`, `__asan_store*` and `__asan_handle_no_return` functions and ignores global variables and stack.

I made investigation and find out that in Linux compiler inserts instrumentation of globals and stack, but Linux use `arm-linux-gnueabi` toolchain.

Can anybody explain why `--param asan-globals=1` and `--param asan-stack=1` don't affect on generated code with `arm-none-eabi` toolchain?
Or just set direction for further searches.

Thanks.

Comment: Hi,  Have you made the address sanitizer work? If yes, could you please possibly share me the sample code?

Comment: Dongguo, hello! Yes, I made it, but I can't send to you OS because it's my work and it don't opened yet. I used Linux implementation as reference. Sorry for waiting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need any special functions calls for stack instrumentation - shadow memory is poisoned via inline stores in function prologue (and unpoisoned in epilogue).

Which GCC version do you use? Instrumentation of globals was done only in GCC 5.0 (in [this patch](https://patchwork.ozlabs.org/patch/416958/)) and wasn't backported to 4.9 branch. Another option option is that you forgot to use `-fno-common` which is [necessary to instrument common symbols](https://github.com/google/sanitizers/issues/776).

Comment: I check gcc versions 5.4 and 6.3.1 from [gcc-arm-embedded](https://launchpad.net/gcc-arm-embedded) and yesterday I build 7.1 and all the same - `__asan_register_globals` and `__asan_unregister_globals` are not used.
That about stack instrumentation, how compiler know where shadow memory is located? I don't use `-fasan-shadow-offset=` option because shadow start address, in my realization, computed depends on configuration params.

Comment: @LakeevRoman : Unfortunately variable shadow offset is not supported by GCC. It's quite doable (it has been recently implemented in LLVM), we just didn't need it for Kasan. So for now GCC will always use fixed address, either one specified w/ `-fasan-shadow-offset` or default.

Comment: @LakeevRoman: Just to double check - do you use `-fno-common` as advised e.g. [here](https://github.com/google/sanitizers/issues/776)? Could you check `echo 'int x = 1;' | ~/install/gcc/bin/gcc -fsanitize=kernel-address --param asan-globals=1 -x c - -S -o- | grep asan`? This prints `call __asan_register_globals` but that's 8.0.

Comment: No, I didn't use `-fno-common` flag. With this flag `__asan_register_globals` and `__asan_unregister_globals` appeared. Thanks!

Can you add this note to your answer?